# Found this code online of creating a game with pygame - can't find error.(Version of python is older in the guide I'm using, if that helps)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, nameerror

specific line of error:

```
if event.type==pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
```

> ```
> NameError: name 'event' is not defined
> ```

the block:

```
position = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
angle = math.atan2(position[1]-(playerpos[1]+32),position[0]-(playerpos[0]+26))
playerrot = pygame.transform.rotate(player, 360-angle*57.29)
playerpos1 = (playerpos[0]-playerrot.get_rect().width/2, playerpos[1]-playerrot.get_rect().height/2)
screen.blit(playerrot,playerpos1)
if event.type==pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        position=pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        acc[1]+=1
        arrows.append([math.atan2(position[1]-(playerpos1[1]+32),position[0]-(playerpos1[0]+26)),playerpos1[0]+32,playerpos1[1]+32])
```

I'm a newbie, would appreciate all the help I can get :)
Thank you!

Comment: Where do you get `event` from. In general the events are handled in a loop. [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get) is missing in your code. e.g. `for event in pygame.event.get():`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing the line where 'event' is defined.

Usually in pygame this line (any line where you use 'event', really),

```
if event.type==pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
```

is run inside a for loop where 'event' is defined like so:

```
# get all the events
for event in pygame.event.get():
    # do something with an event
    if event.type==pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
```